# Для чего нужны только ключевые параметры функции

Tags: python

Где их можно использовать для чего они вообще нужны ?

Comment: Чтобы не было необходимости париться о порядке аргументов, например

Answer (score 0):

Для читаемости и более гибкого механизма передачи аргументов.

Comment: "_более гибкого механизма передачи аргументов_", — раскройте, пожалуйста, мысль.

Comment: @nomnoms12 можно отдельно обрабатывать словарь ключевых аргументов и список позиционных. Ну и любой порядок указания в отличие от позиционных.

Comment: Мне кажется, мы говорим о разных вещах. Не будет списка, речь идёт о только ключевых параметрах: `def f(pos, *, only_keyword_param=None):`. Хотя угадать, что имел в виду автор, не могу.

Comment: @nomnoms12 теперь понял с последним предложением. Использовать *исключительно* ключевые параметры постоянно нет смысла. Но из преимуществ остаётся только читаемость из указанных двух.